# Windows 7 network connection indicator does not change after connecting to network

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit, user-interface

I have recently installed Windows 7 on a computer and  network connection indicator does not change after connecting to network.

I do not know correct terms, so I posted pictures.
When there is a WiFi network available, I get following icon in the lower right part of the taskbar:
[image: wireless networks available]

After I connect to a network, I should get following image,

[image: connected to wireless network]

but instead I get this:

[image: what I get (image same as image 1)]

It doesn't change even when I disable WiFi card and connect to a wired network or when there is no Internet connection available.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After you are connected, can you access the internet?

I found this [link](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/c3ee2c3f-82e5-44c7-8f40-ee7fb7f48c83) that may help you. Comment back to let me know how it went. I will continue to research this for a little bit.

I also found this [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/3f39e49c-fa29-4bbe-b66a-d7aa403957f4).

> ·         Does this happen when
>   computer returns from sleep or
>   hibernation mode?
>
> ·         What is the anti-virus
>   installed on your computer?
>
> 1. Verify relevant service
>
> i.                    Click "Start",
>   go to run, type "services.msc"
>   (without quotation marks) in the open
>   box and press Enter.
>
> ii.                  Click Continue
>   button to verify the administrator
>   permission.
>
> iii.                Right click the
>   "Network Location Awareness" service
>   and choose Properties.
>
> iv.                 On General tab
>   click Start.
>
> v.                   Choose Automatic
>   next to Startup type.
>
> vi.                 Click OK.
>
> 2. Even scan and repair the WMI Repository Database on the computer.
>      To do this, follow these steps:
>
> i.           Click Start, type cmd in
>   the Start Search box, and then press
>   ENTER.
>
> ii.         At the command prompt,
>   type the following commands. Pressing
>   ENTER after each command line:
>
> winmgmt /verifyrepository
>
> winmgmt /salvagerepository
>
> iii.       Restart the computer.

[Here](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/45033-windows-7-wireless-icon-wrong.html) is another possible fix to this solution:

> You may also want to check for updates
>   drivers for your wireless card. Here
>   is another idea: disable IPv6 in
>   TCP/IP settings:
>
> Search -> View Network Connections
>   Identify the WiFi adapter/NIC
>   Double-click on it and go to
>   Properties Uncheck Internet Protocol
>   Version 6 (IPv6)
>
> This could be:
>
> An old driver problem A problem with
>   IPv6 A registry problem which may
>   require clearing the networks.
>
> Under Network and Sharing Center you
>   should only have one active network
>   when under WiFi.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see, network connection works fine. I can access Internet and other computers in LAN and other computers can access me and everything looks good, except the image.

Comment: I'll try it out and report.

Comment: I tried everything those links suggested, and it didn't help.

Comment: Ooo, I found another link that is perfect. I am trying to decipher the solution. http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/45033-windows-7-wireless-icon-wrong.html